# Find all functions which satisfy $f(x)=f(x^2), f(-0.5)=2017$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Q: Find all functions $f:(-1,1)\to \Bbb R$ such that satisfy the following $3$ conditions below.

1. $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.
2. $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for every $-1<x<1$
3. $f(-\frac12)=2017$

My solution is

The only $f$ satisfying condition above is f(x)=2017, since f is continuous at $x=0$, $f((\frac12)^{2^n}) \to f(0)=2017$
let $f(a) \neq 2017$ for some $-1<a<1$
then, $a^{2^n} \to 0$ so $f((a)^{2^n}) \to f(0) \neq 2017$, which makes contradiction

Is this valid? If not, how should I solve this?

Comment: 3rd condition is f(-0.5)=2017

Comment: I can't see your whole prove. I think the point is to find the value of  $f(0)$, so I think it's probably valid.

Answer (score 1):

You're idea is OK, but it can be made more formally correct:

If $p$ is fixed in $(-1,1)$, we define $a_0 = p$, $a_n = a_{n-1}^2$ by recursion.
Then for all $n$ $f(a_n)=f(p)$, which is shown by induction on $n$ and condition 2.
So $f(a_n) \equiv f(p)$ is a constant sequence.

Also, $|a_n| \le p^{2^n}$ (e.g. by induction) so as $|p| < 1$, $a_n \to 0$. Now continuity at $x=0$ gives that $f(p) = \lim_n f(a_n) = f(0) = f(\lim_n a_n)$.

As $p$ was arbitrary, $f$ is a constant function, so the value $f(-\frac12)=2017$ shows it is the constant function with value $2017$. It's of course the unique solution.